# Using date() function but needs a different format

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

When I am printing my code in the console I am getting date and time in different format than I require

Please see my code for `time.ts` below:

```
 let start = new Date();
 console.log(start);
```

I am getting the result in the below format [this is what is coming in my console window] -

`Fri Nov 10 2017 16:27:22 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

What I want is -

> 2017-01-02 17:15:16

How do I achieve this? I only want the value of `start` variable to be `2017-01-02 17:15:16`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Date pipe`, here is an example:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe){}

     ngOnInit() {
        let start = new Date();
        const dateAsString = this.datePipe.transform(start, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss');
        console.log(dateAsString)
     }
}
```

It injects the `DatePipe` and converts and prints the date in the `ngOnInit`

Comment: i tried to add a new method and it says [ts] Cannot find name 'DatePipe'

Comment: Did you also add the import? `import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';`

Comment: error gone but how do i console.log this inside oninit to check ? sorry i am bit new to angular , here is my `file.ts` code ,  please advise

Comment: I updated my answer to make it more clean with an `inject` and bigger example

Comment: thanks, worked..please accept my question, i have accepted your answer